# Help with drawing an Molecular Orbital (MO) diagram for organometallic complex

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, organometallic-compounds

I do not understand how to draw the MO diagram for this question, i appreciate any help you can give on my 3rd yr Chem.

Have i understood this correctly?

QUESTION: Using an MO bonding picture and resonance structures explain the reactivity of the following complexes:
(i)  (CO)5W=C(OMe)Ph and Et3N
(ii)   (Np)3Ta=CH(tBu) and (CH3)2C=O (Np = neopentyl)

So for (i), would (CO)5 be written on one side and W on the other of the MO diagram?

Or would (CO)5W be written on one side and C(OMe)Ph on the other of the MO diagram?

Steps needed for ANSWER:

1.
Identify the atomic orbitals: Here, we're dealing with a transition metal (Tungsten, W) bonded to a carbonyl group (CO) and a carbene (=C). W has 5d, 6s, and 6p orbitals, C has 2s and 2p orbitals, and O has 2s and 2p orbitals. The atomic orbitals involved in bonding would be a subset of these.

2.
Identify the ligands: Here, the ligands are CO and =C(OMe)Ph. The CO ligands are known as pi-acceptor ligands because they can accept electron density from the metal into their pi* antibonding orbitals. This back-bonding interaction would result in the formation of metal-carbon pi bonds, in addition to the metal-carbon sigma bonds. The carbene =C(OMe)Ph would also form a sigma bond and potentially a pi bond with the metal.

3.
Combine atomic orbitals of the same symmetry: Next, atomic orbitals of the same symmetry can overlap to form molecular orbitals. For instance, the s orbital of W can overlap with the s orbitals of C and O to form sigma bonds. Similarly, the p orbitals of C and O can overlap with the d orbitals of W to form pi bonds.

4.
Fill in the electrons: Electrons are then added to the molecular orbitals, starting with the lowest energy orbital. In this case, the number of electrons would be determined by the sum of the valence electrons from W, C, and O.

5.
Identify the HOMO and LUMO: These are the highest occupied molecular orbital and lowest unoccupied molecular orbital, respectively. To determine the reactivity of the molecule.

> *Side note: More general information if this is all new to you A transition metal ion has five d orbitals of equal energy, which split
> into different energy levels when ligands bond to the metal ion. Some
> ligands cause a large splitting of the d orbitals (known as
> strong-field ligands, like CN- and CO), while others cause a small
> splitting (known as weak-field ligands, like I- and Br-).
>
> In a complex ion, the metal atom or ion is at the center of the
> molecule, while the ligands are atoms, ions, or molecules that are
> bonded to it. The d-orbitals of transition metals are the last set of
> orbitals to be filled in accordance with the Aufbau Principle. These
> orbitals have specific shapes and orientations and are part of the
> outermost (valence) electron shell, which participates in chemical
> bonding.
>
> The type of bonding in transition metal complexes involves
> coordination bonds, which are a type of covalent bond where the metal
> ion (acting as a Lewis acid) accepts a pair of electrons from a ligand
> (acting as a Lewis base). This is different from typical covalent
> bonding, where each atom contributes one electron to the bond. In the
> case of transition metal complexes, the ligand donates both electrons.
> Now, let's discuss the orbitals: s orbitals: These are spherical in
> shape. Every energy level has one s orbital, and it can hold up to 2
> electrons.
>
> p orbitals: These have a dumbbell shape. Each energy level from n=2
> onwards has three p orbitals, each of which can hold up to 2
> electrons. d orbitals: These have more complex shapes. Each energy
> level from n=3 onwards has five d orbitals, each of which can hold up
> to 2 electrons. These orbitals are critical for transition metal
> chemistry, because they can participate in various types of bonding.
>
> The bonding between the d-orbitals of the transition metal and the
> ligands can take several forms. As I mentioned before, sigma and pi
> bonding can occur. Sigma bonding involves the head-on overlap of
> orbitals and is generally stronger. Pi bonding involves the side-on
> overlap of p or d orbitals and is generally weaker. In many cases,
> transition metal complexes exhibit sigma bonding with their ligands
> and also have pi back-bonding, particularly with pi-acceptor ligands
> like CO.*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the question has already been solved online. Here is a screenshot of how it looks

[image]

[image]

[image]

If these don't show, please feel free to follow [this reference link](http://alpha.chem.umb.edu/chemistry/ch611/documents/Exam211-18-09solutionskey.pdf)